# how to add button when listview is updated?

Tags: android, listview, button

[image]

I'm working on App which get the data from GCM , After this I display the data in the listview and when get new data from GCM , I add these new data to the listview and I used this code

```
public void updateListView2(List<FeedItem> newItems) {
    for(FeedItem item : newItems)
    {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Title : "+item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // this to add the new items at the top of the list
        listAdapter.insert(item, 0);
    }
    // to retain the position of the listview after updated
    int lastViewIndex = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    View view = listView.getChildAt(0);
    int top = (view == null) ? 0 : view.getTop() ;
    listView.setSelectionFromTop(lastViewIndex, top);
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       //this to add the button programitcally like "New Stories"
    Button updateBt = new Button(this);
    updateBt.setText("Updated");
    feedLayout.addView(updateBt);
}
```

but when I tried to add the button like this "New Stories" I failed , Nothing is viewed !! so can anyone Help Me  .

Comment: have you called notifyDatasetChanged() method of the listView after adding the button?

Comment: No ,  but I don't try to add the button in the list , I just need to notify the user the listvew is updated, and when click on the button he goes to the top of the listview  like this FB image :)

Comment: check out this link...http://stackoverflow.com/a/32200221/2826147

Answer (score 0):

I would play with visibility (VISIBLE && GONE). When you get info you don't have to add the button but make it visible and with visibility GONE after clicking it (or whatever the event you want).

This may make you easier to work with hierarchies of views because you define the button in your xml layout (with visibility gone by default, at the top or in the position you need it) and change its properties dinnamically.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do is add that button and place it wherever you want in your xml layout file and set

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

or

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

when you need the button to display, display it from java code like this

```
myButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

follow this, you'll get no issues.