# Go to top button at top of recyclerview

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, floating-action-button

Hi i am trying to create a button on top of my recyclerview purpose of button will be to goto top of list. Just like facebook "new stories"button shown in attached picture.
[image]

One option that i got is to create a Floating Action Button and display it in on top of recyclerview but after searching i found out that it's better to create own FAB rather changing android's FAB layout. Which bring me back that how to create custom FAB.

Comment: I have tried FAB, created something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31202622/floating-action-button-being-a-square but i think this isn't the proper way. Also tried simple button with z-index but that isn't working either.

Comment: I think you're looking for this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32200275/how-to-add-button-when-listview-is-updated